# Trigger Spring Batch as part of Web Application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on a web application, as part of the requirement the application users clicks on a button which is available on the UI so that behind the scenes `spring-batch` application should trigger and process the data over 15 minutes.

Since the application is web based users can invoke the batch process concurrently at any given point of time.When user performs click action the UI doesn't need to wait for the batch status or response.

I already have the `spring-batch` process ready which is written in 
`SimpleJobLauncher`, to solve this I am planning to code a REST endpoint to invoke the `spring-batch` however am not sure about handling the multiple requests from UI.

I am wondering how can I a port my existing synchronous batch process to the new application.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `SimpleJobLauncher` uses a synchronous task executor to launch jobs. In your case, you need to use a asynchronous `TaskExecutor` implementation with the job launcher. This will ensure that jobs are launched concurrently. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}
```

This is explained in details in the [Configuring a JobLauncher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobLauncher) and [Running Jobs from within a Web Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer) sections of the reference documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mahmoud Ben Hassine. Please let me know how can I handle my services  not wait for the response after the batch job is invoked.

Comment: With a asynchronous task executor, the job will be run by a background thread and your controller will return the http response immediately without waiting for the job to finish.